# One avot-patriarch-fathers tag, three, or four?

Tags: discussion, specific-tag

We've been tagging all questions about the *avos* (the patriarchs, viz Abraham, Isaac, and Jacob of Genesis) with [avot-patriarch-fathers](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avot-patriarch-fathers). Occasionally (two or three times in my memory) people have used specific tags for the individual *avos*; I've merged these into the main tag. But we have 67 [avot-patriarch-fathers](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avot-patriarch-fathers) questions, a number of which are about one or two of the *avos* only/primarily, and people may want to search for questions about any one of the *avos* specifically. Plus, the fact that people keep adding tags for specific *avos* makes it seem likely that they'll continue to do so.

I therefore propose that we have four tags: [avraham-avinu](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avraham-avinu), [yitzchak-avinu](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yitzchak-avinu), [yaakov-avinu](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yaakov-avinu), and [avot-patriarch-fathers](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avot-patriarch-fathers), with the latter used only for questions about the *avos* as a group or about all three equally. (There may be no questions for [avot-patriarch-fathers](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avot-patriarch-fathers) then. I haven't checked.)

Please upvote/downvote this depending on whether you support this proposal; and offer alternatives in answers so people may upvote/downvote them.

Comment: Similar unresolved issue with respect to shabbat: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1156/merge-all-shabbat-tags .  Are there general principles of general vs specific tags that we should be talking about?

Comment: If you have 4 tags, I see a lot of people using both when (for example) they have a question about Avaham Avinu

Comment: @Menachem, so what do you think we should do? if you have a firm idea, would you please post it as an answer so people can upvote it (even if it's the status quo of one general tag only)?

Comment: @msh210: I don't really have a solution, the only real problem is if people run out of tags. Is there a concept of meta tags, where one tag just references other tags? It would only work when sorting by tag, so that if (for example) you clicked on the avot tag, all the posts tagged with Avraham, Yitzchak, or Yaakov would show up.

Comment: @Menachem, pretty sure there's no such thing. Feel free to [file](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) a [meta-tag:feature-request]. We can however have a tag whose associated text is something like "do not use this tag; use x, y, or z instead".